# how to encrypt in swift like android cipher?

Tags: swift, encryption

hi i am developing app in android and swift, encrypt in android using

```
 public static String Encrypt(String text, String key)
        throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
    byte[] b= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len= b.length;
    if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);

    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BASE64Encoder encoder;
    encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(results);
}
```

and server side using RIJnadal lgorithm to get it but swift side i am using Cryptoswift library

```
        let key = privateKey // length == 3

    let iv = "0123456789" // lenght == 16

    let s = string
    let enc = try! s.aesEncrypt(key, iv: iv)
    let dec = try! enc.aesDecrypt(key, iv: iv)
    print(s) //string to encrypt
    print("enc:\(enc)") //2r0+KirTTegQfF4wI8rws0LuV8h82rHyyYz7xBpXIpM=
    print("dec:\(dec)") //string to encrypt
    print("\(s == dec)") //true
```

it produce error Block size and Initialization Vector must be the same length!
how to fix

Answer (score 6):

The difference between Rijndael and AES is that AES is a subset. AES has a block size of 128-bits (16-bytes) and key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bits.

Here is some example Swift code using Common Crypto and the hardware encryption engine, note that using the hardware encryption engine is 500 to 1000 times faster than a pure code implementation:

Add Security.framework to the project
Add #import  to the bridging header.

Swift 2.x:

```
func testCrypt(data data:[UInt8], keyData:[UInt8], ivData:[UInt8], operation:Int) -> [UInt8]? {
    let cryptLength  = size_t(data.count+kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    var cryptData    = [UInt8](count:cryptLength, repeatedValue:0)

    let keyLength             = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
    let algoritm: CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    let options:  CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(CCOperation(operation),
        algoritm,
        options,
        keyData, keyLength,
        ivData,
        data, data.count,
        &cryptData, cryptLength,
        &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.removeRange(numBytesEncrypted..<cryptData.count)

    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }

    return cryptData;
}
```

## Example from deprecated documentation section:

**AES encryption in CBC mode with a random IV (Swift 3+)**

The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data

`aesCBC128Encrypt` will create a random IV and prefixed to the encrypted code.
`aesCBC128Decrypt` will use the prefixed IV during decryption.

Inputs are the data and key are Data objects. If an encoded form such as Base64 if required convert to and/or from in the calling method.

The key should be exactly 128-bits (16-bytes), 192-bits (24-bytes) or 256-bits (32-bytes) in length. If another key size is used an error will be thrown.

[PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) is set by default.

This example requires Common Crypto
It is necessary to have a bridging header to the project:
    `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`
    Add the `Security.framework` to the project.

This is example, not production code.

```
enum AESError: Error {
    case KeyError((String, Int))
    case IVError((String, Int))
    case CryptorError((String, Int))
}

// The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data
func aesCBCEncrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data) throws -> Data {
    let keyLength = keyData.count
    let validKeyLengths = [kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192, kCCKeySizeAES256]
    if (validKeyLengths.contains(keyLength) == false) {
        throw AESError.KeyError(("Invalid key length", keyLength))
    }

    let ivSize = kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    let cryptLength = size_t(ivSize + data.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    var cryptData = Data(count:cryptLength)

    let status = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {ivBytes in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, kCCBlockSizeAES128, ivBytes)
    }
    if (status != 0) {
        throw AESError.IVError(("IV generation failed", Int(status)))
    }

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0
    let options   = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    let cryptStatus = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        cryptBytes,
                        dataBytes, data.count,
                        cryptBytes+kCCBlockSizeAES128, cryptLength,
                        &numBytesEncrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.count = numBytesEncrypted + ivSize
    }
    else {
        throw AESError.CryptorError(("Encryption failed", Int(cryptStatus)))
    }

    return cryptData;
}

// The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data
func aesCBCDecrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data) throws -> Data? {
    let keyLength = keyData.count
    let validKeyLengths = [kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192, kCCKeySizeAES256]
    if (validKeyLengths.contains(keyLength) == false) {
        throw AESError.KeyError(("Invalid key length", keyLength))
    }

    let ivSize = kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    let clearLength = size_t(data.count - ivSize)
    var clearData = Data(count:clearLength)

    var numBytesDecrypted :size_t = 0
    let options   = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    let cryptStatus = clearData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCDecrypt),
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        dataBytes,
                        dataBytes+kCCBlockSizeAES128, clearLength,
                        cryptBytes, clearLength,
                        &numBytesDecrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        clearData.count = numBytesDecrypted
    }
    else {
        throw AESError.CryptorError(("Decryption failed", Int(cryptStatus)))
    }

    return clearData;
}
```

Example usage:

```
let clearData = "clearData0123456".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
let keyData   = "keyData890123456".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
print("clearData:   \(clearData as NSData)")
print("keyData:     \(keyData as NSData)")

var cryptData :Data?
do {
    cryptData = try aesCBCEncrypt(data:clearData, keyData:keyData)
    print("cryptData:   \(cryptData! as NSData)")
}
catch (let status) {
    print("Error aesCBCEncrypt: \(status)")
}

let decryptData :Data?
do {
    let decryptData = try aesCBCDecrypt(data:cryptData!, keyData:keyData)
    print("decryptData: \(decryptData! as NSData)")
}
catch (let status) {
    print("Error aesCBCDecrypt: \(status)")
}
```

Example Output:

```
clearData:   <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>
keyData:     <6b657944 61746138 39303132 33343536>
cryptData:   <92c57393 f454d959 5a4d158f 6e1cd3e7 77986ee9 b2970f49 2bafcf1a 8ee9d51a bde49c31 d7780256 71837a61 60fa4be0>
decryptData: <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>
```

Notes:
One typical problem with CBC mode example code is that it leaves the creation and sharing of the random IV to the user. This example includes generation of the IV, prefixed the encrypted data and uses the prefixed IV during decryption. This frees the casual user from the details that are necessary for [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

For security the encrypted data also should have authentication, this example code does not provide that in order to be small and allow better interoperability for other platforms.

Also missing is key derivation of the key from a password, it is suggested that [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) be used is text passwords are used as keying material.

For robust production ready multi-platform encryption code see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor).

Comment: Not able to find kCCKeySizeAES128,kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding which libs are you using?

Comment: Common Crypto via Security.framework. Add Security.framework to the project
and add #import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h> to the bridging header. Added that information to the project. Also see [AES encryption in CBC mode with a random IV (Swift 2.3)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7026/aes-encryption#t=201610061229144192402) in SO Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your IV has 10 bytes, not 16 (as you have in comment). Block size for AES is 16 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin , plz give any example related to my topic